# Java JPA date 14 hours ahead

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, timezone

I'm using `JPA` to query `mysql` database on `CentOS6`.

## Environment information:

```
[~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

[~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.17 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

[~]# tomcat version
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
Server built:   Jun 9 2017 19:56:49 UTC
Server number:  7.0.78.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-754.17.1.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_121-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

[~]# date
Mon Mar  9 01:21:20 CST 2020

[~]# date -R
Mon, 09 Mar 2020 01:21:23 +0800

[~]# ls -al /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Jun  3  2015 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai
```

## /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone='+08:00'
```

## Time zone config of MySQL:

```
show variables like '%time_zone%';
----
system_time_zone    CST
time_zone   +08:00
```

## Libs:

```
'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.19',
'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.0.12.Final',
'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.6.RELEASE',
```

## Connection string:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/saa?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai
```

## JPA mapping:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class XXX {
    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATA)
    private Date date;

    //...
}
```

## Table `mytable` has a `DATE` type column `date`

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S'), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) from mytable;
----
'2018-12-31 00:00:00', '1546185600'
```

## Java query:

```
logger.debug("{}({})", DateFormatUtils.ISO_DATETIME_FORMAT.format(date), date.getTime());
----
2018-12-31T14:00:00(1546236000000)
```

As you can see, the date java get is `14 hours` ahead of the one in database.

I know the `CST` timezone has different meaning in java and mysql, so I configured them as a lot of documents suggested. But still it doesn't work.

- I have already use `TemporalType.DATA`, why the Date object still has hour section?
- What else should I try to get correct Date in java?

Comment: this issue looks similar to this [solution](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11396).

Comment: 1546185600 and 1546236000(000) aren't the same time anyway. They are 50400 seconds apart: that's 14 hours.

Comment: @AndyTurner That is what I'm asking, they should be the same.

Comment: Agree that it looks weird. And not answering your question at all, but could you avoid the `Date` class? That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use an appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: 1546185600 is 2018-12-30T16:00 UTC equal to 2018-12-31T00:00+08:00 (China Standard Time?) So it seems your database is using the start of day in your time zone for converting from date to Unix timestamp (seconds since the epoch). 1546236000000 is 2018-12-31T06:00 UTC, as you say, 14 hours later. This is equal to 2018-12-31T00:00-06:00. So it may seem that your Java interprets CST as North American Central Standard Time (America/Chicago or America/Winnipeg). Why that is I cannot tell.

Comment: @OleV.V. the same `date` and `date -R` output on my Mac, but can get correct date from same mysql, so I guess there is some thing wrong in JVM on CentOS.

Comment: @OleV.V. jdbc URL with "serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai" should just do the job. My bad, I use redis and redis cached the value which queried previously.

Answer (score 2):

The redis **caches** the value queried previously when jdbc string doesn't have `serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai` in query string.

After using `serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai` and deleting the cache, it can read date with correct timezone now.

As [MySQL Connector/J 8.0 Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) states, it doesn't have property <s>useLegacyDatetimeCode</s>, so only `serverTimezone=Asia/Shanghai` is required.